# Как изменить раскладку по умолчанию в Mint 10 LXDE?

Tags: lxde, linux-mint, linux

После запуска системы раскладка клавиатуры английская, а мне нужна русская, так как в большинстве случаев я пишу на русском, ну и иногда нужен английский. Неудобно после входа в систему менять раскладку, хочется чтобы была сразу русская раскладка. Менюшку с изменением раскладки по умолчанию в  GUI я не нашёл, а как поменять её другим способом я не знаю. Прошу помочь новичку в настройке Linux Mint 10 с рабочим окружением LXDE. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Система - Параметры - Клавиатураназвания могут немного отличаться, но суть таже. Русский мышкой перенеси над английским. Должно сработать.