# Изменить символ в раскладке (замена символа Ё в раскладке на #)

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура

на сайте нашел [неполный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/342524/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-mint-10-lxde)

скрипт или в настройках что изменить прошу подсказать

Comment: Раскладки хранятся в `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. AFAIK нормального способа отредактировать их на пользовательском уровне нет, так что придётся править по месту (желательно в отдельном файле, чтобы не потёрлись при установке пакета)... формат файлов довольно простой и понятный из множества примеров... задавать потом как обычно — своим любимым конфигуратором xkb, или вручную...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы не зарываться «глубоко в недра» `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, для такой мелкой задачи можно воспользоваться возможностями [xcompose](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose) (см., например, вопросы здесь, касающиеся xcompose — их [немного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcompose)).

для этого достаточно добавить в файл `~/.XCompose` строку:

```
<Cyrillic_IO>: "#"
```

это для прописной <kbd>Ё</kbd>. аналогично, при необходимости, и для строчной:

```
<Cyrillic_io>: "#"
```

после этого x-клиент, в котором вам нужна такая подмена, достаточно перезапустить (если нужно во всех x-клиентах, то проще перезапустить x-сессию).

Comment: # Все заработало, отредактировал /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru

Comment: xcompose в репо ubuntu 16.04 - нет

Comment: есть, конечно. это же часть функциональности x-сервера. а он у вас **уже** стоит. и, значит, *xcompose* — **уже** работает.

Comment: в терминале which xcompose - пусто. 
`stat ~/.XCompose     
stat: cannot stat '.XCompose': No such file or directory`
`uname -a Linux xerus 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: это не отдельная программа, это **функциональность**, [реализованная в x-сервере](https://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man5/Compose.5.xhtml). файла `~/.XCompose` по умолчанию, конечно, нет. просто создайте его и запишите всё, что нужно.